# best and secured way of storing paypal api credentials

Tags: ios, security, ssl, paypal

I'm creating an iPhone application that integrates the PayPal API for iOS. The API requires the API credentials when sending a request. I read the PayPal API and it says

> Never send Express Checkout requests from your mobile application directly to PayPal. The requests require your PayPal API credentials. Placing your credentials on mobile devices exposes you and PayPal to unacceptable security risks. Send Express Checkout requests only from secure servers.

My question is, what is the best way of storing the API credentials so as to decrease the possibilities for my credentials being exposed or hacked? Is attaching the credentials to an iPhone build risky? Why or how? Is storing these credentials on a secure server reliable enough?

EDIT: how can keychain access api on iOS can help me with this?

Comment: the idea is to create your own server software that uses those credentials. They are never revealed to anybody. You don't put the credentials in a text file on your server and download them to your app. The quote says it all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting the API keys in your app  is completely insecure. Via a verity of techniques, anyone who can download the app or gets their hands on a phone with the app on it can simply read the API key. This holds even if you do what @MatthiasBauch suggested  and download the secret later. It also holds even if you do what @Rexeisen suggested and obfuscate the string.

You best bet is to  user apple's built in subscription services to handle payments ( which may not be applicable and they take a cut but is likely more secure than what you can do on the phone)

In the likely even that you don't want to or can't do that, give each instance of the app a unique id that they register when they download with a server you control. That sever than has the paypal credentials and will make api calls on their behalf . This way, if any given phone is stolen/ has its api key to your server read, you can simply revoke that key and your paypal API keys are still safe. Important caveat: until you actually revoke that app's key, anyone who has it can still use it to make what ever calls your server supports. This could be a very bad thing.

Answer (score 1):

It is risky as you can run the Strings utility on just about any app (try it, it's kinda scary)  and get the strings from the code. Generally I'd recommend packaging the secrets in the app, but leave them on a secure server elsewhere. If you must put it in the app, one thing you can do is obfuscate the strings so it's not obvious.

```
NSString *secret = kTwitterClientSecret;
NSData *secretData = [secret dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *key = @"Twitter";
[secretData obfuscateOrDeobfuscateWithKey:key];
NSString *documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@-%@", documentsPath, key, @"output"];
[secretData writeToFile:path atomically:NO];
NSLog(@"Wrote obfuscated data to: %@", documentsPath);
```

Where obfuscateOrDeobfuscateWithKey is a category on NSData

```
// Inspiration from: http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/obfuscation-encryption-of-string-nsstring.html
- (void)obfuscateOrDeobfuscateWithKey:(NSString *)key
{
    // Get pointer to data to obfuscate
    char *dataPtr = (char *) [self bytes];

    // Get pointer to key data
    char *keyData = (char *) [[key dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] bytes];

    // Points to each char in sequence in the key
    char *keyPtr = keyData;
    int keyIndex = 0;

    // For each character in data, xor with current value in key
    for (int x = 0; x < [self length]; x++) {
        // Replace current character in data with current character xor'd with current key value.
        // Bump each pointer to the next character.
        *dataPtr = *dataPtr ^ *keyPtr;
        dataPtr++;
        keyPtr++;

        // If at end of key data, reset count and set key pointer back to start of key value
        if (++keyIndex == [key length]) {
            keyIndex = 0, keyPtr = keyData;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can declare a constant to be something like

```
static unsigned char const kTwitterClientSecret[] = {
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, ... etc ... 
};
static unsigned int const kTwitterClientSecret_len = LENGTH;
```

Then to get the string back you can do

```
[NSString deobfuscatedStringWithBytes:kTwitterClientSecret length:kTwitterClientSecret_len key:@"Twitter"];
```

Where this is a category on NSString

```
+ (NSString *)deobfuscatedStringWithBytes:(const void *)bytes length:(NSUInteger)length key:(NSString *)key
{
    NSData *deobfuscatedData = [NSData dataWithBytes:bytes length:length];
    [deobfuscatedData obfuscateOrDeobfuscateWithKey:key];
    return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:deobfuscatedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

This will do very simple obfuscation and will not show up in strings.

Comment: obfuscating the strings is a really really poor idea. Its security through obscurity only and anyone with access to the binary can still get the data

Comment: @imichaelmiers in that case, apple and me will have the access to my binary, is there any  way that other people who has my app read it's binary? in jailbroken device or not. thanks for the comment btw :)

Comment: @janusfidel On a jail-broken device, trivially, since the user can execute what ever they want or just dump the file system and mount it on something.

On non jail broken devices, I suspect the same techniques that are used for taking forensic copies of iphones would give you the binaries on them. From there it is ,again, a simple matter to mount the image and read/grep/whatever the binary in question.

Comment: @imichaelmiers I do understand what you mean :) thanks. what about if I use keychain access? would that help?

Comment: @janusfidel . I mean that there are tools that, even on a non jailbroken phone, can copy the contents of an iphone. You then mount the copy in say linux and look at the binary (e.g. with a hex editor). As to keychain, not really. Keychain protects data on the phone from others accessing it, not the user of the app. They know the PIN, so they can derive the keys used to encrypt the data. Remember, the threat here is not the phone getting lost, but a black hat installing the app and reading the api keys out of it.